# Swift 2, UIView position and UITextField event

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, swift2, uitextfield

I have a problem, I currently have a working animation to move the UIView up and down on click of a button but the problem is that I have a UITextField and when it's pressed for the first time it returns UIView to it's storyboard position but from the second press and up it works great

```
    func forgotPass() {

    let xPosition = signInView.frame.origin.x

    var yPosition = signInView.frame.origin.y

    print(yPosition)

    let heightOfView = signInView.frame.height

    let widthOfView = signInView.frame.width

    if x % 2 == 0 {

        UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5, animations: {

            yPosition -= 120

            self.signInView.frame = CGRectMake(xPosition, yPosition, widthOfView, heightOfView)

        })

        UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5, animations: {

            self.forgotPassView.alpha = 1

        })

    } else {

        UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5, animations: {

            yPosition += 120

            self.signInView.frame = CGRectMake(xPosition, yPosition, widthOfView, heightOfView)

        })

        UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5, animations: {

            self.forgotPassView.alpha = 0

        })

    }

    x += 1
}

func forgotPassEss() {

    let xPosition = signInView.frame.origin.x

    let yPosition: CGFloat = 146.0

    let heightOfView = signInView.frame.size.height

    let widthOfView = signInView.frame.size.width

    signInView.frame = CGRectMake(xPosition, yPosition, widthOfView, heightOfView)

}
```

and to trigger the action

```
         emailForgotPass.addTarget(self, action: #selector(ViewController.forgotPassEss), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.AllEvents )
```

and

```
        @IBAction func forgotPassButton(sender: AnyObject) {

            forgotPass()

        }
```

Comment: get frames in `viewDidLayoutSubviews`